# iScroll to loop automatically?

Tags: jquery, ios, iscroll

Does anyone know how to make [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) act like carousel, is there a way to make [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) automatically loops within the 'ul'?

Because I would like to use it on iOS, I've been trying to figure it out..

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work.

```
setInterval(function () {
   myScroll.scrollToPage('next', 0, 400);
}, 2000);
```

You of course have to check when you reach the end of the carousel (curPageX).

======

**Update**: With iScroll 5, the code has changed slightly, you'll want do something like this to start the automatic looping; while optionally stopping the auto-scrolling after a user interaction (touch/swipe).

```
/* start auto-scrolling */
myInterval = setInterval(autoScroll, 5000);

/* function handles the looping of the carousel */
function autoScroll() {
  var currPage = myScroll.currentPage.pageX + 1;
  if(currPage == myScroll.pages.length) {
    myScroll.goToPage(0, 0, 250);
  } else {
    myScroll.goToPage(currPage, 0, 250);
  }
}

/* stops auto-scrolling on swipe (using jQuery .on() method) */
myScroll.on('beforeScrollStart', function() {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

Hope that helps anyone who stumbled upon this page!

Answer (score 1):

afaik, iScroll did not provide such function.
you can try Sencha Touch, it has various kinds of UI component, 
and this is the doc of Carousel provided by Sencha Touch 2.0 
[Sencha Touch 2.0 Carousel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel)

Comment: I upvoted this. That is not the purpose how iScroll should be used. There are several other Carousel plugins available in jQuery Mobile and other frameworks.